# Redux-form - Validate on demand - wizard form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, wizard, redux-form

I'm using redux-form to build a multipage form.

I have a multi "page" form.
My parent form is initialize like this :

```
Parents = reduxForm({
    form: 'my-form',
    enableReinitialize: true,
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
})(Parents);
```

And multiple component/page displayed conditionaly like this :

```
{(step === 1) && <Intro onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} loading={submitting}/>}
{(step === 2) && <Motifs onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onSubmitFail={this.handleSubmitFail} loading={submitting}/>}
{(step === 3) && <Fichiers onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onSubmitFail={this.handleSubmitFail} loading={submitting}/>}
{(step === 4) && <Confirmation onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onSubmitFail={this.handleSubmitFail} loading={submitting}/>}
{(step === 5) && <Terminee onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onSubmitFail={this.handleSubmitFail} loading={submitting}/>}
```

`this.handleSubmit` is a function that call `this.props.handleSubmit()` and add or remove `1` to step if the server respond http 200.

On the components `<Motifs>` for example i initialize redux-form like this :

```
Motifs = reduxForm({
    form: 'my-form',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    validate: validateMotifs // validation function
})(Motifs);
```

And for each of my form components/pages i have some button to previous/next like this : 
`<NavFormButton loading={loading} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} onSubmit={onSubmit}/>`

When i click next i want to validate and submit the form. It's working.
But when i go previous i just want to submit the data so they are saved but don't want to validate because the user may have not fill all the fields.

How should i do ? Am i following the good path ?

Having a lot of trouble to understand how to do this correctly ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can try to reinitialize form with the current values, submit and then go to the previous form.

`dispatch(initialize('my-form', newInitialValues))`

See more [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1991)

Also if you are using v6, then you should look `shouldAsyncValidate` function to run async validation when you need it. Official [docs](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-shouldasyncvalidate-params-boolean-optional-)